# Disable Outlook “Metered Connection” warning in OUTLOOK not in WINDOWS

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How is it possible to disable warning of OUTLOOK about connecting via a metered network?
I do not want to set the network itself not metered in Windows.
I do want OUTLOOK not to stop syncing via metered networks.
Thanks

Comment: That's a system wide setting, not per app, therefore not possible.

Comment: @ChanganAuto while setting a network connection metered (cost=fixed rather than unrestricted) is an OS setting (system wide) certainly *how outlook responds to that setting* is an app-specific setting, no? Certainly there are no *technical* difficulties with Outlook (or any app) implementing a UI settings toggle "ignore metered network connection", correct?

Answer (score 2):

***Nope, we cannot achieve that.***

The metered network is a Windows network setting, not Outlook.

So, we are not able to disable warnings in Outlook individually. Just like these articles mentioned, you can’t somehow whitelist Outlook for any or all of your connections or prevent Outlook from requesting the network costs before connecting. To bypass this warning, you have to change the “costs” setting for your network connection so it will no longer be a metered network.

References:

[Metered network warning and Outlook not connecting automatically](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/metered-network-warning)

[Turn Off the Metered Network Warning in Outlook](https://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/turn-off-the-metered-network-warning-in-outlook/)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: the information you provided was very helpful. That said, I strongly suggest to add a brief of the solutions that are suggested in the posts you linked to. (both of them - regularly turn off via Wi-Fi settings, and manually modify the registry)

Comment: Rather than beating around the bush, why don't we say what's *really* going on. A metered connection prevents *windows updates* and since Windows 10 Microsoft *urgently* wants all users to install all updates all the time. You can find a million complaints about this policy online. And consider how different are the use cases. If on a metered connection, most users will not want to pay-by-the-Gig for a windows update. On the other hand, a majority of users who *just opened Outlook to check their email* will likely accept the cost in this case. Much smaller cost also.